# Logic Apps Transform Json Array

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

**I am getting below Json and want to send request to Teams Chanel , Conection is setup and able to send complete Json Array but i want to send in Format like mention.**

Json Recieved

`{ "body": [ [ "2024-03-15T06:06:16.299Z", "Res1", "Integ1", "Process1" ], [ "2024-03-15T06:07:19.469Z", "Res2", "Integ2", "Process2" ], [ "2024-03-15T06:08:32.976Z", "Res3", "Integ3", "Process3" ] ] }`

**Post to Teams Channel**

**Timestamp- 2024-03-15T06:06:16.299Z

RG- Res1

Service- Integ1

Process- Process1


Timestamp- 2024-03-15T06:07:19.469Z

RG- Res2

Service- Integ2

Process- Process2


Timestamp- 2024-03-15T06:08:32.976Z

RG- Res3

Service- Integ3

Process- Process3**

I tried to use  `triggerBody()?['body'][0]'` for TimeStamp but getting exception . Appriciate if I can get some guidance how this can be achived . I am new in logic apps and in learning phase.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations?tabs=consumption#select-action) action and the [`join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#join) function to achieve the desired result - nothing else is required.

I am assuming that indeed the following request is sent to your Logic App:

```
{ "body": [ [ "2024-03-15T06:06:16.299Z", "Res1", "Integ1", "Process1" ], [ "2024-03-15T06:07:19.469Z", "Res2", "Integ2", "Process2" ], [ "2024-03-15T06:08:32.976Z", "Res3", "Integ3", "Process3" ] ] }
```

And not the following:

```
[ [ "2024-03-15T06:06:16.299Z", "Res1", "Integ1", "Process1" ], [ "2024-03-15T06:07:19.469Z", "Res2", "Integ2", "Process2" ], [ "2024-03-15T06:08:32.976Z", "Res3", "Integ3", "Process3" ] ]
```

First, the `Select` action will help you convert the array of arrays into an array of strings.

Code View of the `Select` action:

```
{
    "inputs": {
        "from": "@triggerBody()?['body']",
        "select": "@join(item(), '\n')"
    }
}
```

Screenshot of the result:

[image]

Then, the `join` function will help you convert this array of strings into a string in desired format.

Code View of the [`Compose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations?tabs=consumption#compose-action) action that uses the `join` function:

```
{
    "inputs": "@join(body('Select'), '\n\n')"
}
```

Output of the `Compose` action:

```
2024-03-15T06:06:16.299Z
Res1
Integ1
Process1

2024-03-15T06:07:19.469Z
Res2
Integ2
Process2

2024-03-15T06:08:32.976Z
Res3
Integ3
Process3
```

Screenshot of the result:

[image]